# Switching from sh shell to bash shell as default terminal when log in

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal

I was installing some stuff through the terminal while in bash, all went well but then instead closing the window which instructions for installing said, I typed "exit". When I opened a new window - on the top there wasn't bash anymore and output was this:

```
Last login: Wed Apr 20 15:49:54 on ttys000
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

And no prompt line so I couldn't even type - ctrl +c also not working.
I was searching everywhere online - tried in terminal - preferences - general - command  (complete path): /bin/bash  then I opened another window shell and again couldn't type and it said the same above - ... process completed.

So I tried to switch in the preferences to /bin/sh and opened again a new window shell and then I got the prompt line to type and on the top of the terminal sh but I need bash on the top.

The last try - I opened .profile and put there SHELL=`type -P bash`
exec bash -l  which is described bellow and found it here at stackoverflow. When I opened a new terminal window I got the same message "....process completed" and again I can't type anything. Also on the top there is not sh anymore just terminal. I would really appreciate some help. Thank you!

11
down vote
This is slightly kludgey, but you can cause bash to be the shell you're using upon login by creating a .profile file in your home directory, containing
SHELL=`type -P bash`
exec bash -l
This will cause the ksh session to be replaced with a bash session. You won't have to type exit (or ^D) twice, as you would if you manually started a new bash session every time you logged in. And typing

```
echo $SHELL
```

will even return the path to bash.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related sites http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux) OR http://superuser.com . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: Something clearly messed up your bash startup scripts. Look at `$HOME/.bashrc`, `$HOME/.bash_profile`, `$HOME/.profile`, etc. and see what the story there is.

Answer (score 3):

You can set your login shell using the `chsh` command:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash jana
```